# Deep Copy vs Shallow Copy vs Reference Copy

Tags: java

so I am still struggling to understand how to create methods that take different copies and return em. Here are the questions below and my attempt is below that.

Write a method that takes a reference to an array of StringBuffer objects as a parameter and returns a reference,shallow,and deep copy of that parameter array. Note that not every position of the array will refer to a StringBuffer object, some might be null.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //probOne();
    StringBuffer[] abc = new StringBuffer[]{new StringBuffer("Anakin"),new StringBuffer("Luke"),new StringBuffer("Ben")};
    System.out.println(abc);

    StringBuffer[] cba = refCopy(abc);
    System.out.println(cba);
    
    cba = shalCopy(abc);
    System.out.println(cba);
    
    cba = deepCopy(abc);
    System.out.println(cba);
}

public static StringBuffer[] refCopy(StringBuffer[] sa) {       
    StringBuffer[] sb = sa;
    return sb;
}

public static StringBuffer[] shalCopy(StringBuffer[] sa) {
    StringBuffer[] copy = new StringBuffer[sa.length];
    copy=sa;
    return copy;
}


public static StringBuffer[] deepCopy(StringBuffer[] sa) {
    StringBuffer[] copy = new StringBuffer[sa.length];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
        copy[i] = sa[i];
    }
    
    return copy;
}
```

EDIT 1: I changed the deep copy method

```
    public static StringBuffer[] deepCopy(StringBuffer[] sa) {
    
    StringBuffer[] copy = new StringBuffer[sa.length];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
        copy[i] = new StringBuffer(sa[i]);
    }
    
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: Your `deepCopy` is shallow, and `shalCopy` and `refCopy` are both reference copies. A real deep copy would create a new StringBuffers for each one in the array.

Comment: is it correct now?

Comment: According to the question text you should also account for entries that are null, and leave them as null instead of creating a new StringBuffer for them

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you have this class:

```
class B {
    int b;

    B(int val) { // constructor
        b = val;
    }
}

class A {
    B a;
}
```

## Reference Copy

The easiest one, it's basically where when you change one object, you change the other object.

```
A orig = new A();
A copy = orig;
copy.a = new B(5); // now orig's a variable is also a B object with value 5
```

## Shallow Copy

The second easiest one, it makes a new object, the the fields are copied over as reference copies.

```
A orig = new A();
A.a = new B(5); // random value
A copy = new A();
copy.a = orig.a; // copy the b variable by reference
copy.a.b = 5; // affects orig's b variable.
```

## Deep Copy

Copies all the variables not by reference.

```
A orig = new A();
A.a = new B(5); // random value
A copy = new A();
copy.a = new B(orig.a.b); // copy the b variable not by reference
copy.a.b = 5; // doesn't affect orig's b variable.
```

Comment: In the shallow copy section, `A.a = new B(5);`. I think you wanted to say: `orig.a = new B(5);`