# Shallow Copying Class Objects vs. String Variables

Tags: c#, .net, immutability, shallow-copy, mutability

```
string a = "John";
string b = "Doe";

a = b; // Shallow copying strings
b = "Elon Musk";

Console.WriteLine(a); // Output: Doe
```

This prints "Doe", meaning the change in one variable is NOT reflected to the other variable. However, when "boxing in" the string property into a class and performing a shallow copy with class objects, the change in one object is actually reflected to the other object.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// ----

Person person1 = new Person { Name = "John" };
Person person2 = person1; // Shallow copy

Console.WriteLine(person1.Name); // Output: John
Console.WriteLine(person2.Name); // Output: John

person2.Name = "Jane"; // Modifying the property via person2

Console.WriteLine(person1.Name); // Output: Jane (changes are reflected in person1)
Console.WriteLine(person2.Name); // Output: Jane
```

I am trying to understand what the reason is that the changes are reflected in 2nd case, but not reflected in 1st case. Both class objects and string type are reference-type, therefore, the change should be reflected in the 1st case too, right? Please help me understand what the difference between the two cases that is causing this difference in behavior.

I know that string type is immutable. Are class objects mutable? Is that the reason for the difference between two cases?

Note: I did check previously asked questions, and I could not find a similar question.

Comment: `Person person2 = person1; // Shallow copy` <-- This is **not** a "shallow copy" - that's a reference-copy. A shallow-copy would require a `new Person` then copying all properties over (though only 1 level-deep, if it were 2+ levels it would be some kind of deep-copy).

Comment: @Dai thanks for your comment. could you by any chance provide some links where I can learn more about this topic? I couldn't find any proper definitions in C# documentations, and I also couldn't find a definition of `reference copying` on the internet and how exactly it differs from shallow and deep copying. Maybe the world really needs a medium blog post from one of you guys. This information seems so obscure to me

Comment: The terms I used are rather... _fundamental_ in CS+SE, which is why MS's C# documentation doesn't bother to explain them. It would be like asking someone on [bicycles.SE](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/) to explain what the term "wheel-spoke" means. Best I can do is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62398990/deep-copy-vs-shallow-copy-vs-reference-copy - it's for Java, but applies to C# too.

Comment: @Dai - as a non native speaker I have no idea what "wheel-spoke" is, let me go ahead and ask on bicylces.SE (only kidding - googled the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string` is a reference type (immutable one but still), local variables store reference to some memory occupied by it, even if string was mutable `b = "Elon Musk";` does not change the data stored by reference in `b` it changes the reference itself to a completely new one, i.e. for person sample equivalent would be:

```cs
Person person1 = new Person { Name = "John" };
Person person2 = person1;
person2 = new Person { Name = "Elon Musk" };
```

With corresponding effect on the result.

Read more:

- [Reference types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)
- [When editing an array "in place", why does overwriting the array not work, but overwriting each element does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76717022/when-editing-an-array-in-place-why-does-overwriting-the-array-not-work-but-o/76717067#76717067)
- [Object.MemberwiseClone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.memberwiseclone?view=net-7.0)

  > A shallow copy of the current `Object`.

Comment: does that mean when we do `b = "Elon Musk"`, it changes where b variable points to in memory, but does not update where a is already pointing to. And "Doe" in memory does not get cleaned by garbage collection due to still being used by a. And that is why a stays as "Doe"?

Comment: @Mephisto yes, exactly. Also why do you think it should affect `a`?

Comment: but then why isn't the same thing happening with class objects? is it because class objects are mutable and can have their data modified in memory?

Comment: @Mephisto it happens, update your snippet to the code in answer.

Comment: I understand. So it is all about mutability. Now it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Mephisto yes and no. Strings immutability prevent you from changing strings "properties" as you do with mutable object (i.e. you can't do `b[2] = 'n'`, at least without unsafe) but the "vice versa" behaviour can be observed in both cases.

Comment: how can the vice versa behavior be observed in the case of string variables?

Comment: @Mephisto by "vice versa" I have meant the behaviour you have observed in the question with strings (i.e. assigning reference to another place in memory).